# Angular Dynamic Forms not displaying

Tags: angular, angular7

I am having an issue with dynamic forms that are not displaying correctly though augury says they are part of the form and the config is populated.

My component is retrieving the list of form inputs from a service.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { DynamicFormComponent } from '@/_forms/dynamic-form/dynamic-form.component';

import { FieldConfig } from '@/_interface/field.interface';
import { QAndAService } from '@/_services/q-and-a.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-dynamic-bedroom',
 templateUrl: './dynamic-bedroom.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./dynamic-bedroom.component.css']
})
export class DynamicBedroomComponent implements OnInit {
 @ViewChild(DynamicFormComponent) form: DynamicFormComponent;

 regConfig: FieldConfig[];

 constructor(private qandaService: QAndAService) {}

 ngOnInit() {
 this.getQuestions();
}

private getQuestions() {
  this.qandaService.getQuestions().subscribe((resp: any) => {
  this.regConfig = <FieldConfig[]> resp;
 });
}

 submit(value: any) { }
}
```

Console log is reporting the form.value is undefined.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined 
>   at DynamicFormComponent.get [as value] (dynamic-form.component.ts:21)
>       at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (DynamicBedroomComponent.html:3)
>       at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:22503)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21878)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:22114)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:22056)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21879)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:22114)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:22056)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21879)

Something tells me the form is calling for the fields before the subscribe has finished. Anyone suggest a fix?

*edit added component.html

```
<div class="form">
 <app-dynamic-form [fields]="regConfig" (submit)="submit($event)"></app-dynamic-form>
 <div class="margin-top">
 {{ form.value | json }}
 </div>
</div>
```

EDIT 2:
After further debugging I believe this issue is the dynamic form component is trying to build the form before the item configs have been returned form the service. How can I protect myself against this?

Comment: show the template where u call the `submit`

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka By submit do you mean the dynamic form component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this to work by adding `*ngIf` it my dynamic form tag. What this did was stop the dynamic form from trying to load until it had something in a variable to process.

Example code

```
<div class="form">
 <app-dynamic-form [fields]="regConfig" *ngIf="regConfig !== undefined" (submit)="submit($event)"></app-dynamic-form>
</div>
```